# Changing the type of Element in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

1) In EA we have an Element of type Port in this Element we have to add the child Elements of type Class or Interface or any other type. But for port type the child element can be of type only part. Is there any other elements of other type other than part can be added as child to the port.

2)In MDG we have defined an Element of type class whose stereotype is 'Test Case' .While Creating an element in EA I tried to change that type from Class to Part and assigning the stereotype to 'Test Case' . But the Tagged values that are assigned to this stereotype are not coming after changing the type .

Answer (score 0):

1. Theoretically you can add any element to a `Port` as child when using automation. However, `Port` should have only `Interface` elements. If you try it in the GUI you will automatically be constrained and get the error "move is not supported" or the like.
2. `Part` is a different metatype than `Class`. You can assign the `<<Test Case>>` only to `Class` metatypes, not to `Part`s.

Comment: 1) When we try to add the class type as child element to port type parent through automation EA will throw the IDual Exception.

Comment: I said "theoretically" since the automation ever had some leakage. It seems that it has been fixed here. So it does no longer work and that's correct.